# After which or after that

Tags: word-usage, that-vs-which

She was educated at home until the age of fifteen, "after that" she was sent off to finishing school in Singapore.

Is using "after that" appropriate in this sentence ? Or I should use after which?

What is the difference between the two ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"After which" would be appropriate if it is used to connect the two independent clauses together to form a single sentence. "After that" would be appropriate if you broke it into two sentences: "She was educated at home until the age of fifteen. After that, she was sent off to finishing school in Singapore."